# What is the difference between [ and ) while specifying a set of numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic

I have a text on Algorithms which has these 2 lines in it -

> *random double value in [a,b)*
>
> random int value in [0..N)

What do the notations [ and ) mean?

What's the difference between the 2 lines?

Comment: See: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2571754/159845)

Comment: $[a,b]$ includes both ends in the interval, $(a,b)$ includes neither, $[a,b)$ includes $a$ but not $b$, while  $(a,b]$ includes $b$ but not $a$.  Some people instead write $[a,b]$ and $]a,b[$ and $[a,b[$ and $]a,b]$ respectively

Comment: The key difference between your two lines are the words *double* (double-precision floating-point type, so not necessarily an integer) and *int* (integer type).

Comment: I meant, is there any significance of the '..' between the ends of the intervals? (in the 2nd line)

Comment: As you might guess, `[0..N)` probably means the same as $\{0,1,\dots,N-1\}$.

Comment: So, both the lines actually mean the same? They just tell us the numbers between the endpoints of the interval? ( With the end a/0 inclusive?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a, b)$ means all $x$ such that $a<x<b$.

$(a,b]$ means all $x$ such that $a<x\le b$.

$[a, b)$ ...  such that $a\le x <b$.

$[a, b]$ ... $a\le x \le b$